# Get access to references made inside an external class/DLL (.Net)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dll, reference, cefsharp

I'm using cefsharp (a .Net wrapper for the chrome web-engine as an replacement for the native webbrowser control).
To make it work you must make a reference to four DLL's files in your project and do some initialization, and then add the cefsharp winform control to your form - all that works fine.

But now I would like to make my own DLL file which have all those references, initialization + other code (methods etc.).

And in my main application I will only make a reference to this new DLL and through that get access to the cefsharp webbrowser control.

But I'm not able to access those "underlying" references.

Is that even possible, or do I have to make references to the cefsharp DLL's in the main project too?

I hope it make sense without all the code (which I can attach if needed of course)

The reason is I want to use cefsharp in many project.

[image]

Comment: You would have to wrap the parts of the `CefSharp API` you wished to expose in your own `API`. Theoretically you should be able to expose your own `API`, embed all the `CefSharp` resources (`managed and unmanaged`), extract them to your executing folder. Likely a fiddly task, depends how much benefit it provides you?

Comment: Okay...at first hand I thought it would be enough to just reference the different object, but that didn't work.
I'll try to look into the wrap thing....thanks for pointing me in the right direction :-)

Comment: CefSharp is already a .Net wrapper for the cef (which is a c++ dll). So if I succeed in making my own wrapper, would it be an issue that I use a wrapper for a wrapper.....actually, from my main project the real chrome web engine will then be 4 levels away as the cef is probably some kind of a wrapper too :-P